# How to find if a data disk in azure VM is used?

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have an OS Disk and Data Disk in Azure. How can I find if the data disk is in use?

Comment: Find the disk in Azure portal and check if it says attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can query unattached disks from Azure CLI -  `az disk list --query '[?managedBy==`null`]'`

[image]

From Azure portal if the "Disk state" field is Unattached & "Managed by" field is empty: "disk > overview > Managed by field"

[image]

For disk usage information go to  Azure Monitor > Virtual Machines > Performance > Logical Disk Space Used %

[image]

Comment: it says it is attached. But how can we know if it is used to store data?

Comment: @BlueClouds you can find the % of disk space used in Azure Monitor Dashboard > Virtual Machines > > Performance > Logical Disk Space Used %

Comment: Can you add that to your answer? that is the answer